# Cannot Find Symbol on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, path, classpath

I have been having some trouble setting up vscode for Java.  I am currently taking a java course on Coursera that provided a jar file.  I added the jar file to the reference libraries but whenever I try to compile the code I get the "cannot find symbol" error.  I have also provided a screenshot of proof and the organization of my file system.  Is the file system optimal?  How should I fix this error?

Screenshot of Visual Studio Code Workspace

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code Workspace]

I have tried restarting vscode and that didn't work and have tried setting the path to the src file and that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you running your project via `Code Runner`? If so, please disable the Code Runner extension and run your project with `Extension Pack for Java`.

Comment: I ran the project with the `Extension Pack for Java` and it works, but why am I unable to compile java files into classes using `javac` in the terminal?  Whenever I try that I still get the same `cannot find symbol` error.

Comment: If your source file referenced the jar file as a dependency, you need to include that jar file when you invoke javac for compilation. For example: javac -cp <path to jar> xxx.java

Comment: like so `javac -cp 'c:\Users\Downloads\stdlib.jar' TrinomialBrute.java`?

Comment: @Arnold Have you tried this command? Is the problem solved?